# Array in MIPS and finding maximum value

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

I'm trying to write an assembly code that deals with arrays and printing the max value in the data segment. Here's what I've done:

```
.data
lst:    .word 2,5,1,3,7,0,6
i:    .word 0                  #counter? for iterating over the lst in order to find the bigger value

.text
loop:
lw $t0, lst
lw $t0, 0($s0)     #first of all,setting the first value in lst to be max value? 
addi $t1,$0,1       #increase the counter by 1
li $t1, 0         #index of array

loop2:
lw $t0, 0($s0)
bgt $t1, $s0, isMax      #if next val is greater than val at $s0, branch to isMax
addi $t1,$t1, 1       #increase counter
j loop2

isMax:
li $v0,1
la $a0, ($s0)       #prints the max value
syscall
j endloop

endloop:
li $v0,10
syscall
```

I've just started learning MIPS assembly and i can say I'm not very familiar with it as of now.

By right, it should print 7 since it's the max number in the lst but it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a good problem description. What happens? Also, have you tried using a debugger to single step the code and see where it doesn't do what you intended? PS: you haven't even set `$s0` to anything. Your algorithm doesn't make much sense either. Furthermore, words are 4 bytes.

Comment: Seems like you branch to `isMax` when you find one value larger than the previous max value. But you have to continue the search as there could be an even larger value later. You cannot print until you have checked *all* the values.

Comment: What environment you use to assemble + run this? If you use one of the SPIM/MARS family tools, they have built-in debuggers, so search the documentation, and spend few days playing with it, until you understand how you can single step over instructions, how to read the register values, and how to check memory values, bonus points for learning how to use breakpoints. Also probably spend some time debugging working examples, to get better idea how the code works. Then try one more time your task (maybe even scrap this one, as it is so much confused).